# TTF font not displaying lowercase letters

Tags: fonts, pdftex, ubuntu, truetype

I'm trying to use an OCR-A font in a LaTeX document to embed a short code.

I've finally got it reading a system font that I've installed (I think from [ocr-a-font](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ocr-a-font/)), which works well in any other application that I've tried it in, including GIMP, Inkscape, and Synfig.

When I try to use it in my LaTeX document, I'm only seeing the uppercase and numeral characters.

```
{\fontfamily{ocra}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont [xxxx-xxxx] }
```

The document is an `article`, with `hyperref`, `enumitem`, and `tikz`, and I'm compiling with `pdflatex`.

MWE (requires font to be installed, so I don't know how useful it will be)

```
% mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\fontfamily{ocra}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont aBcD-0123 }
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `pdflatex mwe.tex`, I only see `BD-0123`.
[image: MWE Output (PDF viewed in Document Viewer)]

Might anyone know what is causing this, and how it could be remedied?

Comment: The `ocra` font has only uppercase letters.

Comment: @egreg the font that I'm using has both uppercase and lowercase letters, how can I tell which font is being used?  http://imgur.com/gN3F7yI

Comment: Not the font you're choosing with the `\fontfamily{ocra}` declaration, which probably is the legacy font found on CTAN.

Answer (score 6):

I have obtained a (not very satisfying) result by downloading OCRA.pfa and OCRA.afm from that site; I then modified the entry in OCRA.afm for z, changing `enc-122` into `z`.

Running `afm2tfm OCRA.afm` and preparing in the same directory the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}

% make the pfa file known to pdftex
\pdfmapline{+OCRA < OCRA.pfa}
% create a new font family
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{OCRA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{OCRA}{m}{n}{<->OCRA}{}

\begin{document}
\xfonttable{U}{OCRA}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output.

[image]

So your document can be

```
\documentclass{article}

% make the pfa file known to pdftex
\pdfmapline{+OCRA < OCRA.pfa}
% create a new font family
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{OCRA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{OCRA}{m}{n}{<->OCRA}{}

\begin{document}
{\usefont{U}{OCRA}{m}{n}aBcD-0123}
\end{document}
```

The `.tfm`, and `.pfa` files can be moved in a directory known by the TeX system, for instance

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/ocra/ocra.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/ocra/ocra.pfa
```

(note the case change) and you can make a small package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{ocra}

\pdfmapline{+ocra < OCRA.pfa}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ocra}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ocra}{m}{n}{<->ocra}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ocratext}{\usefont{U}{ocra}{m}{n}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textocra}{\ocratext}
```

to be saved as `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/ocra/ocra.sty`.

Run `mktexlsr` as super user and then your document can be

So your document can become

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocra}

\begin{document}
\textocra{aBcD-0123}
\end{document}
```

[image]